# Mac Mail "View as Icon" missing in High Sierra?

Tags: mac, email, high-sierra

I upgraded to High Sierra and now the "View as Icon" option in Mail is no longer there.  Anyone know where it went? Is it gone for good :-(

Comment: I just noticed it appears for some attachments but not others. Hmmm.

Comment: Update: the problem only seems to occur for multi-page PDFs.  For single-page PDFs and other attachments like JPGs, the "View as Icon" option is visible.  But for multi-page PDFs, there is no "View as Icon" option.  Perhaps the new Mac Mail client is not recognizing the multi-page PDF properly?

Answer (score 4):

What I was told by my AppleCare chat was that tis is a "Cosmetic Change: for Markup to work on attachments.  You are right that the  view as icon option is still there for text and numbers and for image files, but not for multipage PDFs.  Give Apple feedback on you interest in having this restred.

Found that if you drag the attachment icon within the new message window just a little bit, the "View as Icon" option will appear again when you right-click on the attachment.

Comment: Thanks Floyd.  Do you know the best place to leave direct feedback for Apple?

Comment: https://www.apple.com/feedback/

Answer (score 0):

I found that in Sierra and Mail.app 10.3, even a one-page image would only attach as an icon, and could not be displayed in place. A [workaround](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324111/sierra-mail-app-workaround-for-missing-display-in-place-display-as-icon-ch) is to display the image on your computer, take a screenshot, and attach the screenshot to the email, which will display the image and not just the icon.