# Sierra / Mail.app workaround for missing "Display in Place / Display as Icon" choices?

Tags: mail.app, email, pdf, attachments

The "Display in Place / Display as Icon" choice in Mail.app (accessed via a right-click), [previously removed from High Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300576/mac-mail-view-as-icon-missing-in-high-sierra), has now also disappeared in Sierra running Mail.app 10.3.

Is there a workaround? I have a 160K one page .pdf attachment that I'd like to display in full.

Answer (score 1):

A successful workaround is displaying the visa on your computer, taking a screenshot (command + shift + 4) of the image, and attaching the screenshot to the email. In this case, the screenshot displays fully, showing the image within the email.